# Change section heading for each page

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I would like to change the section heading from whatever its current heading is to something else.

For example :

http://www.bhajansangrah.com/index.php?title=10

If you go to that page then you will see that the first section lists the following :
"૧0 – હખેં પ્રભુની સેવા કરવી"

Well I would like to change that to just say "Gujarati"

There are about 560+ pages that this needs to be done on. Is there a way I can do this via mediawiki api. 
Or anyway I can code something up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [ReplaceText](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aReplace_Text), to replace strings across the wiki. (Use it with care, though!)

And when you do replace it, I would highly recommend using templates for content like that, so that you can easily make further adjustments in the future! Something that you could call like this:

```
{{myTemplate
|gujarati 1       =     ગાતાં ગાતાં બધાં આવો, ...
|gujarati 2       = બાપના પ્રેમે ખબર લીધી, ...
...
|phonetic latin 1 = Gaata gaata badha aavo, ...
...
}}
```

and with Template:myTemplate looking like this  (using the popular pipe hack for creating tables inside parser functions):

```
<includeonly>
==Gujarati==
{| {{#if:{{{gujarati 1|}}}|
{{!}}-
{{!}}૧
{{!}}{{{gujarati 1}}} }}
...
```

Just an example of how it might look, but you get the idea.

The pipe hack consists of creating template called `!` containing only the character `|`. That way you can combine if clauses and table markup, e.g. printing a row only only if there is some content for it (as we do here).

Comment: On a side note, your wiki looks like something that could be using [Semantic MediaWiki](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/) and Semantic Forms, to organize the content in a less hackish way, and to make input easier for not so technical users!